# PHP turning &#189; to ½

Tags: php

This seems to be pretty straightforward. Basically character `½` is stored in database as `&#189;` so browser displays it correctly, however this character is in product name and when I redirect payment to stripe it shows as `&#189;`

I've tried

```
htmlentities(); 
htmlspecialchars(); 
htmlspecialchars_decode(); 
utf8_encode();
```

But none of them works. The only way I can do this is this brutal method:

```
function convertchars($input) {

    $input = str_replace("&#189;", "½", $input);

    return $input;

}
```

But as you can image there are lots of characters I'd skip.

Comment: https://3v4l.org/2uGWJ  . Is this what you want?

Comment: I have tried that as well yet it still ends up as &#189;

Comment: Browsers have been able to display UTF-8 correctly for at least a decade at this point... There shouldn't be anything preventing you from storing `½` directly.

Comment: This is 20 years old system I can't play around with the database.

Answer (score 0):

`$half = html_entity_decode('&#189;', ENT_QUOTES|ENT_HTML5);`

Comment: Same thing mate. Still ends up as &#189;

Comment: You need to put `<meta charset='UTF-8' />` in your `<head></head>` and make sure your actual page *(look in your editor)* is saved as UTF-8.